# adb shell command: mkdir (for creating a directory)

Tags: android, adb, mkdir

I am trying to create a directory through adb shell

I have to create a directory in etc folder which was unsuccessful. I managed to figure out that it is linked to `/system/etc` and tried to create in `/system/etc`, but in both cases I was getting "Read only File System".

How to make it Read write?

I tried switching to super user using "su".

I tried modifying `udev/rules.d` in the host machine:

```
created a file 51-android.rules with " SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"  "
```

I'm still getting the same "Read only File system".

How do I fix this?

Comment: most shell commands work on android...look into the chown command

Comment: This is not an answer to this specific question but it might help others who have a similar problem: `adb shell mkdir` works fine when used in in `/sdcard` or its subfolders. In my case I meant to use it in a subfolder of `/sdcard` but accidentally specified a folder I didn't have access to because my phone isn't rooted. So if you get this error in a folder which you should have access to, you're probably in the wrong folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://android-tricks.blogspot.in/2009/01/mount-filesystem-read-write.html

mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system

This was useful: now i can create directory :)

Answer (score 6):

[Trick] Make a dir (or various) in a non-rooted phone using adb push:

if you use the command

```
adb push myfolder /storage/sdcard0/Download
```

and "myfolder" contains another folders inside, these folders will be created inside "myfolder", which is placed in the "Download" folder of the phone

So, the hack i use to install assets inside my apps:

```
adb push assetfolder /storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.myapp.name/
```

then "assetfolder" contains

```
assetfolder/
   assetfolder/db/mysqlite.db
   assetfolder/img/myimage.png
   assetfolder/json/initial-data.json
```

etc

Then my app has its

```
com.myapp.name/db/mysqlite.db
com.myapp.name/img/myimage.png
com.myapp.name/json/initial-data.json
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This works fine if the folder contains files, but if I try to do this with an empty folder it outputs "0 files pushed, 0 skipped" and doesn't do anything.

Comment: Right @DonaldDuck. I confirm the folder I was copying had files inside. I guess the workaround for your case is adding a small file to the folder, so the copy has successful result

Comment: This is not my finding. If I do 'adb push myfolder /storage/sdcard0/Download', it creates the MYFOLDER folder inside Download and subfolders where one would expect, inside the myfolder folder, not creating the subfolders inside Download as you have stated.

Comment: @Bruce that's what I meant. The folders were in the expected location. But I've read my answer again and it's true it can lead to confusion. It seems I stated what you say. I'll change it.

Answer (score -2):

Login as root, use this commands, it help

adb root
adb remount

Answer (score -5):

Login as root, Just add the following permission to your file in command mode using  Linux Command :

**$ chmod 777 rules.d**

Comment: It's not only unwise to make a system file writable by all users, it's also not a solution to a "read only file system" - the issue is with the mounting of the file system, not the permissions of the individual file.