# How to access a particular internal storage directory in android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to learn android programming. As a beginning, I am trying to understand the internal file system & accessing them. Any help is highly appreciated. Following are my challenges:

1. How to create a 'TEST' folder through the android emulator/Android device monitor? I need to create the folder where the alarms, download, DCIM folder are present.
2. What is the absolute directory path to the 'TEST' folder created? Is it possible to access the TEST folder using the code below:

   ```
   List<File> list = Environment.getDataDirectory()+"/TEST".listFiles();
   ```
3. Does any permission to be mentioned in the manifest for read/write to internal storage?

PS: I use Android Studio.

Comment: have you read this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html ?

Comment: Thanks @Gavriel . Will read it & see. Meanwhile can you please help me with the point 1?

Comment: it's not even clear whether you want a solution in Java or from the command-line via adb

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I don't want to create the folder programatically. I just need to make folder named 'TEST' available in the internal storage. ( So that my code can assume that the particular folder will be available while execution)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373489/adb-shell-command-mkdir-for-creating-a-directory might help

Comment: Why not to use the "files" folder? This folder you can access WITHOUT any permission needed. Its located under data/data/yourAppPkg/files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want something along the lines of

```
File TEST = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "TEST");
TEST.mkdir(); // make directory may want to check return value
String path = TEST.getAbsolutePath(); // get absolute path
```

and permissions

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Further reference

- [Android Open External Storage directory(sdcard) for storing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219312/android-open-external-storage-directorysdcard-for-storing-file)
- [How can I get external SD card path for Android 4.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281010/how-can-i-get-external-sd-card-path-for-android-4-0)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html

Comment: Please note that permission model has been changed as of Marshmallow.

Comment: May I know some more details please?

Comment: What kind of details are you looking for?

Comment: why  getExternalStorage() leading to internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

`File file = new File("storage/emulated/0","yourfoldername/");`

> This worked for me if this doesn't help, then in use

`File(Environment.getobbdir(),"yourfoldername");`